# Business Objects unable to open database connection to MySQL

Tags: mysql, business-objects

We use Business Objects 12 where I work.

BO is trying to pull information from our JIRA Database but I am having some issues getting it to work correctly.

The odbc.ini for BO contains the following:

```
[LiveJira]
Description             = JIRA ODBC Driver
Driver          = MySQL3.51
SERVER          = ip.of.server.here
PORT            = 3306
USER            = bouser
Password                = password
Database                = jiradb
OPTION          = 3
SOCKET          =
```

When I try to connect from the server itself using `isql LiveJira` it connects and I am able to run select statements on the databases.

When the BO client is run on a local laptop it is also able to connect and get the information it needs.

The problem arises when you connect through the BO web interface on the server. The error message is something like:

```
An error connecting to database: 523 80 (WIS 10901)
```

I thought for a while it might be to do with the source address of the query, but since `isql LiveJira` works it does not seem to be address related.

If someone could shed some light on this or knows of an obvious mistake I have made I would be eternally grateful. My searching on google has not provided me with any useful information.

Comment: Is the odbc.ini file change on the local laptop only or is it also on the Business Objects server?

Comment: How sure are you that your BO12 client is trying to connect to `LiveJira`?

Comment: @shrub34 The modified odbc.ini is on the BO server. It is used by the `isql LiveJira` command.

@Karlson Pretty sure. When the BO Universe is configured on the local machine it connects perfectly and everything can be seen. When it is exported to the remote server then it does not work.

Comment: I'm wondering (no experience working with anything but DB2 and SQL Server) if the connection object is not using the ID/password in the odbc.ini file and is instead using the values set in the connection object.  Another verification question, the odbc.ini file you have tweaked is the BusinessObjects odbc.ini file and not the one for the isql command?

Comment: @shrub34 The odbc.ini file that was modified was definitely the one for Business Objects.
It is possible it was using the wrong details. The guy who needed it fixed managed to get it to work using straight JDBC instead of ODBC. So we have it working in a way that he was happy with.

Me may have to come back and sort the ODBC in the future but for now we've a workaround.